# Auto resizing GtkScrolledWindow

Tags: gtk

I have added three GtkHBox inside a GtkScrolledWindow. And set the size of each box as the size of the window. but, when exposed the size of the Scrolled window is resizing by itself.

But, when i do the same with three Layouts ScrolledWindow size is maintained properly. What could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GtkHBox` doesn't have a scrolling interface. `GtkLayout` does. You can add a scrolling interface to something that doesn't have one, by putting it into a `GtkViewport` and then putting the `GtkViewport` into the `GtkScrolledWindow`.